# Get array items by object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, for-loop

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
var entries = [
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article1" },
  { sys: {id:"2"}, fields: "place1" },
  { sys: {id:"3"}, fields: "offer2" },
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article2" },
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article3" },
  { sys: {id:"3"}, fields: "offer2" },
  { sys: {id:"2"}, fields: "place2" }
];
```

Now I want to split this into 3 arrays to accommodate each of the `sys.id` numbers. The result should look like this:

```
var articles = [
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article1" },
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article2" },
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article3" }
];

var places = [
  { sys: {id:"2"}, fields: "place1" },
  { sys: {id:"2"}, fields: "place2" }
];

var offers = [
  { sys: {id:"3"}, fields: "offer2" },
  { sys: {id:"3"}, fields: "offer2" }
];
```

I've already achieved this with the following for loop:

```
var places = [], offers = [], articles = [];

for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
  if (entries[i].sys.id === "1") results.articles.push(entries[i]);
  else if (entries[i].sys.id === "2") results.places.push(entries[i]);
  else if (entries[i].sys.id === "3") results.offers.push(entries[i]);
}
```

However the initial data set that I need to sort in this way will be larger, with more bloated objects, so I'm not sure if a for loop is the most efficient way to do it. Is there a faster and better way?

Comment: If your code works correctly, SO is not the place to ask about it. Try CodeReview maybe.

Comment: You're unlikely to find a more efficient way than you have, but there will be other ways to do it (eg, [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

Comment: @takendarkk the code works for small data sets yes. But I've explained in my question that I don't think this will work well for larger datasets so another method may be required.

Comment: Beware premature optimisation. Try it with larger data and see if it is an issue. You are not making any unnecessary or expensive calls. There isn't much fat to trim in this instance in terms of performance.

Comment: @coop Yes I understand, I can read your question. However, since you haven't tried it on a large data set that means your code works as is. If you run it on a large data set and it is slow and you identify the bottleneck, then that is a specific question to ask about on SO.

Comment: @JamesB: i think the dozens of chars of boilerplate per "case" in a for loop are a bigger expansion concern than perf...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a simple re-usable function that you can use with [].filter():

```
function byID(obj){ return obj.sys.id==this;}

var places = entries.filter(byID, 1), 
 offers = entries.filter(byID, 2), 
 articles = entries.filter(byID, 3);
```

as you can see, it reduces the amount of code you need to write to expand it compared to for-loops.

you can make it even more succinct to expand cases of a single purpose with a simple wrapper:

```
 function filt(n){
    return entries.filter(function byID(obj){ 
      return obj.sys.id==this;
    }, n);
 }

 var places = filt(1), 
 offers = filt(2), 
 articles = filt(3);
```

i used == so that you can hit the number-as-string in the data shown using a quoted number or a real number, but if you want to be strict, then add "use strict" and === to the filter() callback.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify with filter method:

```
 entries.filter(function(x){return x.sys.id ==1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this

```
var map = [
    ["1", "articles"],
    ["2", "places"],
    ["3", "offers"]
].reduce(function(acc, pair) {
    acc[pair[0]] = pair[1]
    return acc;
}, {});

var entries = [
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article1" },
  { sys: {id:"2"}, fields: "place1" },
  { sys: {id:"3"}, fields: "offer2" },
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article2" },
  { sys: {id:"1"}, fields: "article3" },
  { sys: {id:"3"}, fields: "offer2" },
  { sys: {id:"2"}, fields: "place2" }
];

// map and entries can come from a dataset
// this way you can have many different sys.id s 

// hash is your final result
var hash = entries.reduce(function(acc, a) {
   var key = map[a.sys.id];
   acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
   acc[key].push(a);
   return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: `var map= ",articles,places,offers".split(",");` does the same and is simpler to code... ;) - just skip the zero and you have a good number-to-string lookup mechanism via arrays.... or just `var map={1:"articles", 2:"places", 3:"offers"};` if you need to get sparse...

Comment: The thing is his `sys.id`s are string not integers

Comment: all keys in js are strings (including array index), though since it's loose-typed it doubly doesn't matter... good news huh?